# Water + RF + Spark = Continuous Fire

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, hydrogen

Can anyone explain the physics of what is happening in the following video?
https://youtu.be/p8xYUDiSGDk?t=37

Is this process Radiolysis?
At what radio frequency & power level is h20 disassociated into H2 & O?
What if any affect does the salt in the h20 have on the process?

Comment: Radiolysis is chemical decomposition by ionizing radiation and there isn't that much of it there, or these people would be dying from it. I don't know whether these videos are real or fakes. That it can be done with sufficiently strong RF fields and salt water is pretty likely, the main question is whether there is a power regime where the water breaks down without boiling away in no time... and, no, this is not a free energy source.

Comment: Hey CuriousOne!  Thanks for responding to my question.  I didn't think it was free energy--just an interesting oddity that might be worth knowing more about.  P.S.:  I still want to finish our dialog from the other day, but it might be a day or 2 before I can get some time.  Take care!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, yes.  13.56MHz was the frequency used and it was a 300W field.
http://www.rsc.org/chemistryworld/Issues/2008/April/ColumnThecrucible.asp

The effect doesn't appear to be well described.  So while the salt is necessary, the exact role it plays isn't detailed.  It could be that some complex with the salt is resonating.

Comment: It's interesting that it seems to yield large quantities of hydrogen-peroxide. As a water electrolysis process it's probably completely unsuitable... but if it's a good laboratory or small scale industrial method to produce hydrogen peroxide, that would make it actually interesting.

Comment: The strange thing is that if large quantities of hydrogen peroxide had been produced in these experiments people would have felt strongly irritated by the vapor containing it... has this been described by those who claim to have done them?

Comment: @BowlOfRed - thanks for the article.  It would be interesting to know the efficiency of the process.

Comment: 300W to disassociate a few atoms and result in a 1W flame? Sounds like an efficiency of 0.003%.